# Error when generating entity with Guid as PK

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, npgsql, abp

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL database with EF core and ABP framwework but when it tries to create the table I got the following error in console

```
[11:58:34 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE "AppClienti" ALTER COLUMN "Id" TYPE uuid;
ALTER TABLE "AppClienti" ALTER COLUMN "Id"
DROP IDENTITY;
```

and this is the visual studio error in Debug

```
Npgsql.PostgresException: '22023: identity column type must be smallint, integer, or bigint'
```

My class is defined as

```
 public partial class Cliente : AggregateRoot<Guid>
  {
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string RagioneSociale { get; set; }
    public double? OrdineLimite { get; set; }
    public float? Sconto1 { get; set; }
}
```

In the DbContext.OnModelCreating it's defined as

```
 builder.Entity<Cliente>(b =>
        {
            b.ToTable(IlDiamanteConsts.DbTablePrefix + "Clienti", IlDiamanteConsts.DbSchema);
            b.ConfigureByConvention(); //auto-configure for the base class props
           ...properties mapping...
        });
```

No specific mapping is defined for the Id column since I think it should be handled by `.ConfigureByConvention`.

Any suggestion? I know that for this particular case I can just have a newid as value and just set it as Key.. but I don't know where to set it.

Thanks

#UPDATE #1

It was my fault, I had a first migration step where I was defining it as int, then when it tries to alter, that error comes up. I've recreated migration scripts from zero and now it works like a charm.

Comment: ABP isn't Entity Framework, not even a *good* way of using Entity Framework. The error is pretty clear - you can't use a non-numeric type as an IDENTITY/Auto-increment column. You didn't post the `Id` property or its configuration but I assume something inside `AggregateRoot` defines an `Id` property whose type comes from the type parameter and has an `Identity` value generation schema. You can't use GUID in this case.

Comment: Ok but I copied it from  the official documentation https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-1?UI=MVC&DB=EF ... so I don't understand why it doesn't work

Comment: I repeat. ABP isn't Entity Framework. It doesn't matter what ABP's documentation says. If the property is defined as `Identity`, then the type must be numeric. Never mind that using GUIDs for PKs is a *bad* idea

Comment: In any case it seems the real problem is executing the migration script unedited. You can generate the full script instead and fix any problems. EF Migrations work well only in simple scenarios anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why is a bad idea of using GUID's as PKs?!

Comment: @Camadas disk fragmentation, bad paging performance, inability to perform range searches, big size results in reduced buffering in RAM. *Some* of these problems can be alleviated by using a sequential GUID algorithm. Check [Bad habits : Focusing only on disk space when choosing keys](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/sql-indexes/bad-habits-disk-space)

Comment: @Camadas btw Aaron Bertrand is StackOveflow's DBA. Apart from a very well know speaker, author and SQL Server MVP.

Comment: so you suggest to move on int keys?

Comment: Why re-create table don't you?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
Thanks didn't know that, going to check the link you gave me